# How to navigate from one visualforce component to another visualforce component

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have 3 tabs in which 3 different components are placed. How can I navigate from a button that is present in one component to another component?

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="MaturityModelAssessmentController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" Id="thePage">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery_UI_1_10_2, 'js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:slds />
    <apex:form id="theform">   
        <div class="slds-scope">
            <div class="slds-page-header">
                <div class="slds-page-header__row">
                    <div class="slds-page-header__col-title">
                        <div class="slds-media">
                            <div class="slds-media__body">
                                <div class="slds-page-header__name">
                                    <div class="slds-page-header__name-title">
                                        <h1>
                                            <span class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate" title="Assessment">Maturity Model Assessment</span>
                                        </h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-tabs_default">
                <ul class="slds-tabs_default__nav" role="tablist">
                    <li class="slds-tabs_default__item" style="background:#005fb2;color:White" title="Item One" role="presentation" id="tab-li-default-1">
                        <a class="slds-tabs_default__link tab1" href="javascript:void(0);"  role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tab-default-1" id="tab-default-1__item">Summary</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="slds-tabs_default__item" title="Item Three" style="background:#0070d2;color:White" role="presentation" id="tab-li-default-2">
                        <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);"  role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-2" id="tab-default-2__item">Incident-Problem</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="slds-tabs_default__item" title="Item Three" style="background:#0070d2;color:White" role="presentation" id="tab-li-default-3">
                        <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-3" id="tab-default-3__item">Availability-Performance</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="slds-tabs_default__item" title="Item Three" style="background:#0070d2;color:White" role="presentation" id="tab-li-default-4">
                        <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-4" id="tab-default-4__item">Service-Finance</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tab-default-1" class="slds-tabs_default__content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-1__item">
                    Summary
                </div>
                <div id="tab-default-2" class="slds-tabs_default__content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-2__item">
                    <c:IncidentProblem type="Incident-Problem" renderingDiv="thePage:theform:tab-default-3:tabid3"></c:IncidentProblem>
                </div>
                <div id="tab-default-3" class="slds-tabs_default__content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-3__item">
                    <apex:outputPanel id="tabid3">
                        Item Three Content 
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                </div>
                <div id="tab-default-4" class="slds-tabs_default__content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-4__item">
                    Item Four Content 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" >

        $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(document).ready(function() {
            $j("#tab-default-2").hide();
            $j("#tab-default-3").hide();
            $j("#tab-default-4").hide();
            $j("#tab-default-1").show();
            $j('#tab-default-1__item').click(function(){
                // var str = document.getElementByClassName('{!$Component.myHiddenField}').value;
                // $j('[id$="myHiddenField"]').val('Incident-Problem');
                $j("#tab-li-default-1").css("background-color", "#1589ee");
                $j("#tab-li-default-2").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
                $j("#tab-li-default-3").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
                $j("#tab-li-default-4").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
                $j("#tab-default-2").hide();
                $j("#tab-default-3").hide();
                $j("#tab-default-1").show();
                $j("#tab-default-4").hide();
            });
            $j('#tab-default-2__item').click(function(){
                $j("#tab-default-2").show();
                $j("#tab-li-default-2").css("background-color", "#1589ee");
                $j("#tab-li-default-1").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
                $j("#tab-li-default-3").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
                $j("#tab-li-default-4").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
                $j("#tab-default-1").hide();
                $j("#tab-default-3").hide();
                $j("#tab-default-4").hide();
            });
            $j('#tab-default-3__item').click(function(){
                $j("#tab-default-3").show();
                $j("#tab-li-default-3").css("background-color", "#1589ee");
                $j("#tab-li-default-1").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
                $j("#tab-li-default-2").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
                $j("#tab-li-default-4").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
                $j("#tab-default-1").hide();
                $j("#tab-default-2").hide();
                $j("#tab-default-4").hide();
            });
            $j('#tab-default-4__item').click(function(){
                $j("#tab-default-4").show();
                $j("#tab-li-default-4").css("background-color", "#1589ee");
                $j("#tab-li-default-1").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
                $j("#tab-li-default-2").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
                $j("#tab-li-default-3").css("background-color", "#0070d2");
                $j("#tab-default-1").hide();
                $j("#tab-default-2").hide();
                $j("#tab-default-3").hide();
            });
        });
        </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**First Component**

```
<apex:component controller="IncidentProblemController" allowDML="true">
<apex:attribute name="type" type="String" description="type" assignTo="{!IncidentType}"/>
<apex:attribute name="renderingDiv" description="a csv list of elements to be rerendered" type="String" required="true"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="divIncidentProblem">
                        <div class="slds-form--stacked">
                            <apex:repeat value="{!allQuestions}" var="qPreview" id="aQPreview">
                                <div class="slds-box slds-theme--default">
                                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                                        <label class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-heading_small">
                                            {!qPreview.orderNumber + ': ' + qPreview.question}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <apex:outputPanel >
                                        <apex:selectRadio layout="pageDirection" value="{!qPreview.selectedOption}" >
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!qPreview.singleOptions}"/>
                                        </apex:selectRadio>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                    <apex:outputPanel >
                                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                                            <div class="slds-form-element__control" >
                                                <label class="slds-form-element__label slds-text-heading_small" for="form-element-01">Reviewer Comments</label>
                                                <apex:inputTextArea styleClass="slds-textarea" cols="" value="{!qPreview.reviewerComments}" style="width:200px"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </apex:outputPanel>
                                </div>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </div>
                        {!$Component.renderingDiv}
                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height: 5rem;">
                            <apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button_brand" action="{!submitResults}" value="Save And Next" reRender="{!renderingDiv}"/>
                        </div>

                    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

I am passing the renderingDiv attribute but still not able to render the third tab.